# Alternative Expression for an inequlaity

Tags: analysis

Suppose $\delta \in (0,1)$, is there any way to express the following inequality as $\delta \geq f(n)$?($n \in R$)

$ \delta^n +\delta^{n+1} \geq 1$

Comment: if $\delta = 0.01$ then $\delta^n+\delta^{n+1} \lt 1$... so the inequality would not be true for $n \in \Bbb N$ for instance... you will need to specify more the conditions of the problem.

Comment: Actually what I am asking is an alternative expression for $\delta^n + \delta^{n+1} \geq 1$. in the form as  $\delta \geq f(n)$, not asking for a $\delta$ to satisfy that inequality for any  $n \in N$. n is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For $\delta\in(0,1)$ and $n>0$, we have
$$\delta^n+\delta^{n+1}\ge 1\iff \delta\ge f(n) $$
where 
$$f(n)=\inf\{\,x\in(0,1)\mid x^n+x^{n+1}\ge 1\,\}$$ 
In other words: $f(n)$ is the smallest positive root of $x^{n+1}+x^n-1$.
There is no simple formula for $f(n)$, though.
But from $2x^{n+1}<x^n(1+x)=x^n+x^{n+1}<2x^n$, we have the simple bounds
$$ \frac 1{\sqrt[n]2}<f(n)<\frac 1{\sqrt[n+1]2}$$

(Note that for $n\le 0$, we have $\delta^n+\delta^{n+1}\ge 2>1$ for all $\delta\in(0,1)$, so we knwo $f(n)=0$ for $n\le 0$).

Comment: That is helpful. Thanks